# "not necessarily" auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

Wie kann man "not necessarily" auf Deutsch sagen?

Also zum Beispiel:

> In den letzten 3 Jahren habe ich so viel gelernt, aber "not necessarily" von meinem Studium.

Passt "nicht unbedingt"?

Comment: Please read the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ja, "nicht unbedingt" passt. Noch wörtlicher ist "nicht notwendigerweise".

Und man würde üblicherweise in deinem Beispiel "wenn auch" statt "aber" benutzen, um den Zusammenhang zwischen den zwei Teilsätzen zu verdeutlichen ("wenn auch" -> das Studium fand definitiv im Laufe der drei Jahren statt / "aber" -> es ist offen, wann das Studium stattfand, es hat sich *nicht notwendigerweise/nicht unbedingt* mit den drei Jahren des Lernens überschnitten).

Dein Satz lautet dann also:

> In den letzten 3 Jahren habe ich so viel gelernt, **wenn auch** *nicht unbedingt / nicht notwendigerweise* von meinem Studium.

Comment: Da die Frage in erster Linie sich auf "not necessarily" bezieht, habe ich die anderen Fehler in der Frage korrigiert und entsprechend die Hinweise aus deiner Antwort entfernt.

Answer (score -1):

Ja. "Nicht unbedingt" ist die beste/gebräuchlichste (="most usual") Formulierung.